# Headphone volume extremely loud before adjusting

Tags: linux, audio, fedora, headphones

If i close or suspend my laptop without headphones plugged in, and then plug headphones back in through the audio jack after turning the laptop back on, the volume of the playback will be abnormally loud. Volume will decrease back to normal after adjusting, so both decreasing and increasing the volume will result in a quieter sound. I am running linux fedora 37.

And just to be clear, I am not talking about volumes that are just annoying. Currently writing this after forgetting about the issue and accidentally blasting music through my earbuds for a moment at a volume high enough to cause physical pain for a few minutes. I hate asking others for help, but this issue is kind of important for me to fix, as it could actually have some very serious negative effects on my hearing.

I'm terrible at articulating my thoughts. I apologize for this in advance, and will gladly clarify anything that I may have expressed in an unclear manner.

Comment: Welcome on SuperUser. I had a similar but opposed problem under Ubuntu, suspending laptop with plugged-in headset, removing them, awaking the laptop resulted in a completely lack of sound from speakers. That time I fixed with  `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/devices/0000:00:1f.3/remove` followed by `echo 1 > /sys/bus/pci/rescan` once that I knew the audio device _address_ (00:1f.3) via `lspci | grep Audio`.  I do not remember in which script I added the lines, search for the script your distro reads in _awakening_ after suspend. Good Luck,